# Is there any option to get data from mobile through a API or something

Tags: laravel, api

I have a Laravel application and there I have created some API for mobile devices which returns data to mobile device. Now I need to create something like API which returns data from mobile, means when call this API or function, I need to get current location of mobile user

Comment: Please show some code. If your question is more general, try asking in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/  instead.

Comment: Actually there is no code, for eg : we are creating API for sending data to mobile..right, i need something like API or function which return data from mobile device

Comment: For eg : i want to get mobile user current location when i call a function or something like API

Comment: If there is no code, there is nothing for Stack Overflow users to comment on or recommend.

Comment: Ok, simply I need an option to get mobile user current location in Laravel backend, Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: It is not about code, i just want to know is there is an option like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to trigger an action on the mobile device from your backend.  The only solutions I see to this are the following:

1. Set a flag on the Laravel backend when the user needs to update it's location and then poll every X minutes on the app to see if a location update is needed.  If the flag is set, the mobile app sends it's location. (This involves extra traffic from your app and it's not real time)
2. Use real time communication with sockets, where communication flows both ways.  Take a look at https://pusher.com and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting
3. Use push notifications.  You can trigger a push notification on your backend that is received on your mobile app. Upon reception by your mobile app, your mobile app sends it's location to the backend.  Take a look at https://onesignal.com and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications